# Importing Excel file in a form then with onSubmit fetch POST it to an API endpoint

Tags: excel

I have an to make an app that will connect with an API. Through this app I will have to send info to the given API. The required parameters are actually in the first row of the Excel file (the headers).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using axios? If yes then you can do something like this.
https://github.com/axios/axios#axios-api

```js
axios.post(url,
    {
        // for GET requests
        params: {
            foo: bar
        },
        // for POST .etc requests
        data: {
            foo: bar
        },
    }

);
```